# how to import libraries to android studio? (Android manifestmerger file)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I know this sounds very easy, but android studio is eating my brains out. I know how to import my current project say `myProject` in to ADT very easily. But I came to know that soon the support for adt will be ending. So i decided to switch to Android studio. I am using the following libraries in my project

1. Commons
2. ActionBarSherlock
3. AndroidImageChacheMaster
4. SlidingMenuMaster

I tried to import the project myProject.

See its Project.Properties file

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-21
android.library.reference.1=../actionbarsherlocklibrary
android.library.reference.2=../Android-Image-Cache-master
android.library.reference.3=../Commons
android.library.reference.4=../google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.5=../SlidingMenuMaster
```

When i tried to import it A.S told me unrecoverable errors and I pasted the library folder as instructed by android studio.

And it project was imported succesfully

but there are two error apparing in the log

```
/home/mukund/StudioProjects/aftercrash62/commenorkingandroid/build/intermediates/manifests/tmp/manifestMerger2026412193483179673.xml

Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 5 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library /home/mukund/StudioProjects/aftercrash62/commenorkingandroid/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml

Error:(5, 5) Execution failed for task ':commenorkingandroid:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 5 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library /home/mukund/StudioProjects/aftercrash62/commenorkingandroid/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.actionbarsherlock/actionbarsherlock/4.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.actionbarsherlock" to force usage
```

please help what is wrong here?

and now my project structure is

```
actionbarsherlocklibrary(empty)
myProject(manifests,java,res,aidl,resources,c,assets)
androidimagecachemaster(manifests,java,res)
commenorkingandroid(manifests,java,res) // i havent imported anything with this name
commons(manifests,java,res)
Gradle Scripts
 build.gradle(Project:myProject)
 build.gradle(Module:actionbarsherlock)
 build.gradle(Module:myProject)
 build.gradle(Module:commons)
 build.gradle(Module:androidimagecachemaster)
 build.gradle(Module:commenorkingandroid)

gradle-wrapper.properties
settings.gradle
```

here are my gradle files

build.gradle(Project:myProject)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
 }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
}
```

build.gradle(Module:actionbarsherlock)

```
 apply plugin: 'java'
```

build.gradle(Module:myProject)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.five.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 16

    ndk {
        moduleName "cr3engine-3-1-1"
    }
 }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
   }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':actionbarsherlocklibrary')
compile project(':androidImageCachemaster')
compile project(':commons')
compile project(':commenorkingandroid')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/epublib-core-latest.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.7.5-7-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
}
```

build.gradle(Module:commons)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:19'
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 15
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.1.0.jar')
}
```

build.gradle(Module:androidimagecachemaster)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 10
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 16
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
compile files('libs/CWAC-AdapterWrapper.jar')
}
```

build.gradle(Module:commenorkingandroid)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 5
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Is your project targeting `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 5` ?

Comment: And I'd suggest to use Gradle dependencies whenever you can. For example, you can use `ActionBarSherlock` by adding this (`compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0'`) to your app `build.gradle` .

Comment: And your `actionbarsherlocklibrary` is `empty` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have added Sherlock as an AAR dep like

`compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'`

you can remove

`compile project(':actionbarsherlocklibrary')`, `include ':sherlock'` line from your `settings.gradle`, then related folder from your project.

And your `targetSdkVersion` can be the same as your `compileSdkVersion` as well.